# How do I query a remote bitcoin node like RPC?

Tags: protocol, json-rpc

I know how to query the blockchain stored on my machine programmatically using bitcoind commands. Is it possible to do the same on a public node?

For example, is it possible to send “getblockcount” over the internet to bitcoinstats.com, hard-coded in the bitcoin source, or to inductivesoul.us, found in the bitcoin.it wiki? What are the steps to do so?

Edit

The quick answer is:

- No, you cannot use bitcoind commands.
- You have to communicate with a remote node using TCP.
- You have to use a different set of commands found in the Protocol Specification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excellent question, and welcome to the community!

#### Short Answer

Maybe.

#### Long answer

Yes, you can send queries to other nodes on the Bitcoin network. Note that these aren't RPC calls, but [Bitcoin's underlying communication protocol](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification). That means that all of the calls will be a little different, and some of them won't exist.

Examples:

- There's no equivalent to `getblockcount` in the underlying protocol. Instead, you can connect to a node and listen for its `version` message, and look at the start_height field.
- Instead of `getrawmempool`, you use `mempool`.
- Instead of `getpeerinfo`, you use `getaddr`.
- There's no equivalent to `stop`, because that would be stupid.

Also, if you're trying to query other nodes on the network, one of these libraries will be very helpful:

- Python: http://protocoin.readthedocs.org/en/v0.1/index.html
  (Use protocoin.clients.BitcoinClient)
- Java: https://bitcoinj.github.io/
  (Use Peer.sendMessge)
- Go: https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/blob/master/wire/README.md

(If you're not using one of these languages, leave a comment.)

Comment: Is there an API library for PHP?

Comment: @rishta Don't think so. Didn't find any while googling.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build  Bitcoin protocol messages.
This Python library can help you do it, some example here:

https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/tree/master/examples